# How to automatically set the widths of the columns and maintain alignments?

Tags: tables

How to automatically set the widths of the columns and maintain alignments, please? Is it possible to set l c alignment using X column? Thank you

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
hdghdggggggggfhgfhdgfhd hggdgfh  gfhdgfhjghjhj hgfhdgjghjgd ghfhgdhgfh hgfdhghdgh hfghgdh fghgf fdghgd gfdhd
\begin{table}
\caption[]{Caption}
\label{pyttab}
\small
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{lccc}
Parameter       & AAAA &  BBBBBBBBBBBBBB &  C\\
Parameter       & A &  B &  C\\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

(vertical lines are introduced for simpler observe columns width. In real table you can remove them)

- Iit is not clear, what you mean with"automatic".
- From showed MWE can be concluded, that you like to have tables with prescribed width (=`\textwidth`).
- For column `X` you need to use `tabularx` table. In it you can use `X` columns (at least one) and columns defined for `tabular` tables.
- An attractive option is use of the `tabularray` package.
- Below are examples of use `tabularx` and `tblr` (defined in `tabularray` package) tables:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}
    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
    \newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
    \newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-2]
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption[short caption]{Caption}
\label{pyttab}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|L|C|c|R|}
    \hline % ?
Parameter       & AAAA &  BBBBBBBBBBBBBB &  C\\
Parameter       & A &  B &  C\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
    
\lipsum[1][3-5]
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption[short caption]{Caption}
\label{tab:tblr}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={X[l] X[c] c X[r]}, vlines}
    \toprule % ?
Parameter       & AAAA &  BBBBBBBBBBBBBB &  C\\
Parameter       & A &  B &  C\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. And is it possible that each column would have different width (according to its contents - C should be significantly narrower) and the same spaces between columns?

Comment: @ElenaGreg, of course. Column types of `c`, `l` and `r`  adopted automatically to width of cells contents, but not enables break of cells contents into more lines. For this you need column types with prescribed width. To make yoursel more familiar with writing of tables, for start see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables

Answer (score 0):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` provides `X` columns width optional arguments for the horizontal alignment: `X[l]`, `X[c]`, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}
\caption{Caption}
\label{pyttab}
\small
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{X[l]X[c]X[c]X[c]}[hvlines]
Parameter       & AAAA &  BBBBBBBBB BBBBB BBB BBB &  C\\
Parameter       & A &  B &  C\\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]